# browser.executeScript("return arguments[0].shadowRoot") not working with chromedriver 96 and higher

Tags: selenium-chromedriver, protractor, shadow-dom

I extensively use this method to locate element inside shadowRoot using Protractor framework.
But after the chromedriver was updated to 96, it has stopped working.
Does anyone knows how to do work around for this in protractor framework

Answer (score 2):

This solution worked for me with Chrome 97:

```
async function getShadowElement(shadowDomContainer: ElementFinder): Promise<any> {
    const shadowRootObject = await browser.executeScript<any>('return arguments[0].shadowRoot', shadowDomContainer);
    const rootKey = Object.keys(shadowRootObject)[0];
    const rootId = shadowRootObject[rootKey];
    return new WebElement(browser, rootId);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

could thinks working using queryselector:

```
async expandUsingQuerySelector(sRoot,sElement){
   var script="document.querySelector('"+sRoot+"').shadowRoot.querySelector('"+sElement+"')";
   try{
      return await browser.executeScript("return "+script );
   } catch( error ) {
      throw error;
   }  
}
```

Comment: perhaps do you mean: _got things working using queryselector_ ? (From "not an answer" below)